# need assistance with while true look at body for more info

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am new to python and I would like to know how to do a loop with while true that if a variable is 1-5 for example it does the if loop I set to it if the variable is bigger than 5 than it will print something and ask for the input again?

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Hello, it is reccomended that you do a little search before asking questions, that being said, I believe what you are looking for is: "python 'for' loops". In the future, it's a good practice to share a piece of your code so we can understand better your problem and how you intent to solve it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps!

```
num = 7

while(True):

    if(num >= 1 and num <= 5): #If num is between 1 and 5 inclusive...
        #Do something.

    else:
        print("Input out of bounds! ")
        num = int(input("Please enter a new number: "))
```

Comment: thanks this helped me alot, but i had to do a few(1) modifications